# PostgreSQL Replication Tools

Tags: postgresql, database-replication

On the postgreSQL's wiki, on the "Replication, Clustering, and Connection Pooling" page ( http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling) , it shows the following example on replication's requirements:

"Your users take a local copy of the database with them on laptops when they leave the office, make changes while they are away, and need to merge those with the main database when they return. Here you'd want an asynchronous, lazy replication approach, and will be forced to consider how to handle conflicts in cases where the same record has been modified both on the master server and on a local copy"

And that's pretty much my case. But, unfortunatelly, on the same page, it says: "(...) A great source for this background is in the Postgres-R Terms and Definitions for Database Replication. The main theoretical topic it doesn't mention is how to resolve conflict resolution in lazy replication cases like the laptop situation, which involves voting and similar schemes."

What I want to know, is where can I find material on how to resolve this kind of situation, and wich would be the best way to do this on PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just answering my own question, if anyone ever finds it: I'm using Rubyrep http://www.rubyrep.org/ and it's working.

Comment: What exact versions of Postgres, `rubyrep` & its various dependency gems did you use? Can you still get it working?

Answer (score 3):

I will have to check into RubyRep but it seems like [Bucardo](http://bucardo.org/) might be a more widely supported option.

Gabriel Weinberg has an EXCELLENT tutorial on his site for how he uses Bucardo. The guy runs his own search engine called [DuckDuckGo](http://duckduckgo.com/) and there are quite a few tips and tricks that are optimized for his use cases.

http://www.gabrielweinberg.com/blog/2011/05/replicating-postgresql-with-bucardo.html

Comment: seems awesome. And better documented. I have a ridiculous small schedule, so I will keep with RubyRep for now (Extremely simple and painless). But if I ever have a chance to refactor this project, I will take a deeper look on Bucardo.